# Error al imprimir valor de objeto

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy armando mi componente y quiero imprimir el valor de un campo de un objeto y me sale un error que no logro entender cual es.

El objeto es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando intento acceder al valor nombre del objeto status me sale el siguiente error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

Este es el codigo de mi componente

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import clientAxios from "../../config/axios";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Damage = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [damage, setDamage] = useState({});

    const getDamage = async () => {
        const data = await clientAxios.get(`/damages/${id}/show`);
        setDamage(data.data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getDamage();
    }, [])

    console.log(damage.status.name)

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Interno: {damage.interno}</h1>
            <h3>Estado del siniestro: {}</h3>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: El error es obvio. Cuando se crea el componente inicializas el estado con un objeto vacío. Es esperado que la línea `console.log(damage.status.name)` explote, porque no es hasta que se resuelva la petición que la propiedad status y name estarán disponibles. Recuerda que el componente primero se renderiza y luego se dispara el efecto (la petición), pero tu código explota sin nisiquiera disparar el efecto. En resumen, quita la linea del `console.log` o bien inicializa tu estado a algo que tenga `status.name`.

Comment: o simplemente puedes usar el operador de [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?`: `console.log(damage.status?.name);`

Comment: Arroja el siguiente error
./src/components/damages/Damage.js 51:28
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (51:28)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     getDamage();
|   }, []);
>   console.log(damage.status?.name);
|   return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", {
|     __self: _this,

Comment: Que versión de node estás usando?

Comment: Si estoy en const [damage, setDamage] = useState({}); porque dicen que tendria que darle un valor predeterminado al objeto?

Comment: porque estas usando `damage.status.name`. damage si tiene valor, pero status no... y tu estas intentando acceder al name del status. Por eso el error dice que estas intentando acceder a la propiedad name de undefined. Si lo inicializas con `{ status: {} }` el error seguro se va. Pero yo me iria por el optional chaining que sugirio @MauroAguilar